# openmpi: printf not waiting for scanf

Tags: c, mpi

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int x;
    printf("Rank: %d\n", rank);
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    

    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

when i run it on 2+ tasks it prints everything, but scanf used once in the end

```
(base) curer:hw4 user$ mpic++ -o a ./-.cpp 
(base) curer:hw4 user$ mpirun -oversubscribe -np 2 ./a
Rank: 0
Rank: 1
7
```

*scanf in the end and i entered 7*

I want to be like that

```
(base) curer:hw4 user$ mpic++ -o a ./-.cpp 
(base) curer:hw4 user$ mpirun -oversubscribe -np 2 ./a
Rank: 0
8
Rank: 1
7
```

*printf Rank i then scanf any number*

Comment: Multi process programs and interactive inputs don't mix very well. If you want user interaction, typical solution is to choose one process which will serve as UI process and spread the data to others as needed.

Comment: Ranks 1 and above likely read from /dev/null, so scanf returns immediately on these ranks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really really want each MPI tasks to do a job one after another, in order, you could synchronize the jobs by a series of `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`.

This a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int read(int rank)
{
    int x;
    printf("Rank: %d\n", rank);
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    return x;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size, send, receive, x;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    send = 1;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        x = read(rank);
        if (size > 1)
            MPI_Send(&send, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(&receive, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        x = read(rank);
        MPI_Send(&send, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    

    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, each task send a message to the next one, and (except the root) wait a message from the previous task before doing the job.

However, as noted in the comments, it is much more common to let a task, typically the root, to do the input job and then distribute the inputs among the task, using `MPI_Bcast` or `MPI_Scatter`.

Comment: already done that thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976805/yksisarvinen
but your code seems to work